# Zend Framework Routing: .html extension

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, url-routing

I know I've seen this done before but I can't find the information anywhere. I need to be able to route with .html extensions in the Zend Framework.

I.E. /controller/action.html should route to the appropriate controller / action.

We have an idea to throw away the .html extension with our .htaccess file but I think changing the route config would be the better solution.

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search on google yielded the following tutorials:

[Extending Zend Framework Route and Router for custom routing](http://my.opera.com/zomg/blog/2007/09/19/extending-zend-framework-route-and-router-for-custom-routing)

[Routing and complex URLs in Zend Framework](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2007/11/16/routing-and-complex-urls-in-zend-framework/)

Comment: The second result is the tutorial I remember reading, so I'll give you the answer.

Comment: CodeUtopia happens to be one of the blogs that I follow regularly.

Answer (score 3):

This is the plugin I've used in several applications:

```
/**
 * Removes .html extension from URI, if present.
 */
class Application_Plugin_RemoveHtmlExtension extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function routeStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        // remove ".html" from the end of the URI
        $url = preg_replace('#\.html$#i', '', $request->getRequestUri());

        $request->setRequestUri($url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the same for an old application.
Here is what worked for me.

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$router = $front->getRouter();
$router->addRoute('routeHTML', 
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex( '([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)\.html', array(),
        array(1 => 'module', 2 => 'controller', '3' => 'action') ,
        '%s/%s/%s.html')
);
```

### References

- [Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex)

Answer (score 0):

The default route (without modules) is:

```
:controller/:action
```

Which you can remove by:

```
$router->removeDefaultRoutes();
```

Then add your version:

```
:controller/:action.html
```

Comment: That doesn't work. The parameter name becomes action.html instead of action.