# url suffix in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to add a .html suffix to my urls in zend. I was wondering the best way to do this.  I'd like all routing/url generation to automatically handle this.

For example

Default:

```
module/controller/action.html
```

Example Route:

```
search/:query
module=default
controller=articles
action=search
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you get now and what would you like to achieve?

Comment: I think he want "site.com/controller/action.html" or "site.com/controller/action/param.html" automagically rerouted by the framework itself

Comment: post a sample from you're routes.ini file or the portion of the bootstrap that registers the routes and we'll be able to point you in the right direction .

Comment: updated the question with a couple of examples. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried the answers here?: [Zend Framework Routing: .html extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472606/zend-framework-routing-html-extension)